# What function can be used to transform the absolute values of 3 sine waves so that their sum is constant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have the absolute values of 3 sine waves, all 120° apart.
[image: P_1, P_2, & P_3]
$$P_1 = |\sin(x\pi)|$$
$$P_2 = |\sin(x\pi+2\pi/3)|$$
$$P_3 = |\sin(x\pi+4\pi/3)|$$

I am looking for a function ($f(x)$) which can take any of these waves as an input to achieve the following.

$${P_1 f(P_1)} + {P_2 f(P_2)} + {P_3 f(P_3)} = 1$$

What is the formula for $f(x)$?

Comment: Is $f(P_j)$ a constant or a function of $x$?

Comment: $f(x)$ and $f(P_1)$ are functions.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(t)=2t/3$. Then $$P_1f(P_1)+P_2f(P_2)+P_3f(P_3)=\frac{2}{3}(P_1^2+P_2^2+P_3^2).$$ It suffices to show that $P_1^2+P_2^2+P_3^2=3/2$.

Recall that $$\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\sin(b)\cos(a).$$ Recall also that $\sin(\pi/3)=\sqrt{3}/2$, $\sin(2\pi/3)=\sqrt{3}/2$, $\cos(\pi/3)=1/2$, and $\cos(2\pi/3)=-1/2$.

Therefore $$ \sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi/3)-\sin(\pi/3)\cos(\pi x)=\sin(\pi x)/2 - \sqrt{3}\cos(\pi x)/2 ,$$ and $$\sin(\pi x)\cos(2\pi/3)-\sin(2\pi /3)\cos(\pi x)=-\sin(\pi x)/2 + \sqrt{3}\cos(\pi x)/2.$$  Squaring and summing gives \begin{align*} \sin^2(\pi x) &+ \sin^2(\pi x)/4 + \sin^2(\pi x)/4 + 3\cos^2(\pi x)/4 + 3\cos^2(\pi x)/4 \\ & -\sqrt{3}\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)/4+\sqrt{3}\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)/4 \\ & = \bigl[1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\bigr]\sin^2(\pi x)+\bigl[\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\bigr]\cos^2(\pi x)= \frac{3}{2}[\sin^2(\pi x)+\cos^2(\pi x)]=3/2.\end{align*}

Comment: This is the most elegant solution, in my opinion.

Comment: In fact, there seems to be a general pattern of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin^2(x\pi+k\pi/n) = n/2$, giving the usual $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$ identity in the case $n=2$ and answering the asker's question in the case $n=3$. I haven’t checked this thoroughly, however.

Comment: Should be obvious, but worth mentioning: Squaring the sine (or cosine) makes taking the absolute value redundant, so that part of the question becomes moot.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

$$\begin{align*}
f(p) &= \begin{cases}
\frac1p, & p> \frac{\sqrt3}{2} = \sin\frac\pi3\\
\frac1{2p}, & p = \frac{\sqrt3}{2} = \sin\frac\pi3\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
pf(p) &= \begin{cases}
1, & p> \frac{\sqrt3}{2} = \sin\frac\pi3\\
\frac1{2}, & p = \frac{\sqrt3}{2} = \sin\frac\pi3\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
\end{align*}$$

---

For $x = \frac{n}3$, $n\in\mathbb Z$,

$$\begin{align*}
&P_1f(P_1) + P_2f(P_2) + P_3f(P_3)\\
&= \left\lvert\sin\frac{n\pi}3\right\rvert f\left(\left\lvert\sin\frac{n\pi}3\right\rvert\right) + \left\lvert\sin\frac{(n+2)\pi}3\right\rvert f\left(\left\lvert\sin\frac{(n+2)\pi}3\right\rvert\right) + \left\lvert\sin\left(\pi+\frac{(n+1)\pi}3\right)\right\rvert f\left(\left\lvert\sin\left(\pi+\frac{(n+1)\pi}3\right)\right\rvert\right)\\
&= \left\lvert\sin\frac{0\pi}3\right\rvert f\left(\left\lvert\sin\frac{0\pi}3\right\rvert\right) + \left\lvert\sin\frac{2\pi}3\right\rvert f\left(\left\lvert\sin\frac{2\pi}3\right\rvert\right) + \left\lvert\sin\frac{1\pi}3\right\rvert f\left(\left\lvert\sin\frac{1\pi}3\right\rvert\right)\\
&= 0+ \frac12 + \frac12\\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$

For $x \in\left( \frac{n}3,\frac{n+1}3\right)$, $n\in\mathbb Z$,

$$\begin{align*}
P_1&: & x\pi &\in \left( \frac{n\pi}3, \frac{(n+1)\pi}3\right)\\
P_2&: & x\pi+\frac{2\pi}3 &\in \left( \frac{(n+2)\pi}3, \frac{(n+3)\pi}3\right)\\
P_3&: & x\pi+\frac{4\pi}3 &\in \left( \pi + \frac{(n+1)\pi}3, \pi + \frac{(n+2)\pi}3\right)\\
\end{align*}$$

Exactly one of $P_1, P_2, P_3$ is $>\sin\frac\pi3$:

$$\begin{align*}
P_1f(P_1) + P_2f(P_2) + P_3f(P_3)
&= 0+ 0 + 1\\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$